# Excel chart (shape) pasted as Bitmap will not adjust width in VBA?

Tags: excel, bitmap, width, shapes

I have a chart in a spreadsheet that I want to copy as a bitmap and place somewhere else within the same sheet.  My code is below, although there's not much to see.  No matter what I change .width to, the width of the chart does not adjust to what I tell it to.  However, the width will change if I change .Height.  This indicates that the pasted Bitmap image insists on retaining its original proportions.

Is this property specific to Bitmap objects, and is there a way around this problem without changing the paste format to something other than Bitmap?

Thanks for your help.

```
Set AB = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
With AB
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("AB1").Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("AB1").Top
    .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("AB100:BM100").Width
    .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("AB1:AB50").Height
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the bitmap you pasted has "*Lock Aspect Ratio*" set (Format Picture -> Size & Properties). In this case, Excel will change the Width of the bitmap *after* you set the Height (to preserve the bitmap's aspect ratio).

Use **.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse** before you set the Height and Width properties.